# Is there a wildcard character in AWS EventBridge rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I'm creating a rule for EventBridge and I want the rule to match the following structure:

```json
{
  "id": "<string>",
  "changes": {
    "name": {
      "old": "old name",
      "new": "new name",
    },
  }
}
```

Inside of the `changes` object, I don't know what the keys are. Once an attribute is modified, I'll receive the key name, the old value, and the new value in the format referenced above. I want to verify that the `changes` object exists. According to their [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-exists-matching), I can only use the `Exists matcher` on leaf nodes and not intermediate nodes. Is there a wildcard character I could use to do something of the following:

```
{
  "detail": {
    "id": [{
      "exists": true
    }],
    "changes": [{
      *: {
        "old": [{
          "exists": true
        }],
        "new": [{
          "exists": true
        }],
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly you can't do this. Instead, it would be better to send all your events to a **lambda functio**n, and the function would take care of filtering and re-distributing the events further down your message pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

#### New in 2023: EventBridge announces support for [wildcard filters in rules](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/10/amazon-eventbridge-wildcard-filters-rules/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=offbynone&utm_campaign=Off-by-none%3A%20Issue%20%23250)

You can now use the `*` wildcard characters to match string values in event patterns.

Docs are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-wildcard-matching).  Escape the splat character (`\*`) to match a literal `*`.